# Error in simple directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am learning Angular and was trying to create a simple directive given in a book. The code is given below.

I am getting the error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` on line
`template: '<div>Hi there </div>',`

I just can't figure out what is wrong. Can you ?

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<script src="angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var appModule = angular.module('app', []);

appModule.directive('hello', function()
{

    return 
    {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>Hi there </div>',
        replace: true
    };

});

</script>
</head>

<body>

    <hello></hello>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
return 
{
```

to this

```
return {
```

**Explanation:** In the first case, when the `{` is on a different line. It actually mean return **undefined**, follow by an **unreachable block statement**. And in the block there is a syntax error.